# Populate Multi-Select widget names from related values

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a multi-select widget bound to a table that only contains relations. I want to use the related values for each record to populate the multi-select name.

```
Parent-Table 
 - Child-Table-One
 - Child-Table-Two
```

No matter which way I try using the multi-select name paths, **only the first record name in the multi-select gets populated** with the related value from the related child table, the others just display the record ID of the Parent Table.

**Do I need to use a function somehow to iterate through all records to get the related values for every record?**

Answer (score 0):

Binding to the Relation should get you a list of records. Assuming you're trying to get list of the display names, this should work:

```
(@datasource.item.Child1).concat(Array.from(@datasource.item.Child2))
```